# RC circuit with both DC and AC input voltages

Tags: capacitor, resistors, ac, filter

In my circuit, V3 creates a DC signal at 2.5V. V2 creates a sine wave that 0.2V peak to peak centered at 0.1V.

I'm wondering why at Node 1, the voltage is a sine wave with 0.2V peak to peak that is centered at 2.5V? I understand that the C1 is supposed to remove the DC component of V2, but is there a way to reason through this using Kirchhoff's voltage law?

[image: RC circuit with both DC and AC input voltages]

Comment: *I understand that the C1 is supposed to remove the DC component of V2* - that's enough of a reason - why should you want another reason?

Comment: By superposition, I understand you can add the two voltage's together, but is there a reason why the resistor R1 has to be there? If you short it out, node 1 just becomes 2.5V and superposition no longer applies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DC component. Replace AC source with its equivalent impedance (0). Apply Kirchoff, with your knowledge of C's impedance at DC. That should give you the DC component of the voltage at Node 1.

AC component. Replace DC source with its equivalent impedance. Apply Kirchoff, bearing in mind the two impedances are complex. That should give you the AC component.

Superposition. Simply add the two waveforms.

Comment: Ah yes. Superposition is the conceptual reason I was looking for. Is there a reason why the resistor has to be there though?

Comment: Perform the calculations with the resistor value set to 0 and find out.

Comment: Got it - by superposition, when setting V3 to 0 and V2 on, without the resistor, node 1 would be ground. After applying superposition and adding the component voltage values at node 1, only 2.5V remains.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the capacitor as a tiny generator. When the alternating source reaches its positive peak, the capacitor has a positive polarity towards the alternating source. So a negative polarity towards Node 1.
[image]

And when the alternating source reaches a negative half cycle, the polarity is reversed.

[image]

So you will get output within 2.5 +/- 0.2 volt.